# CICD using gitLab with .NET Framework?

Tags: gitlab

My company used .NET framework 4.6.2 and GitLab for version control.

When we finish a feature, we have to use Remote Desktop Connection to connet to a remote desktop, and connect to a remote desktop again, than paste the code we build to replace the file in the remote server.

Is there any way to done this workflow automatically?

I have create a CI pipeline in GitLab, it can build the code automatically, but I don't know how to deploy the code to the remote server.

Many Thanks ‌‌

Answer (score 0):

There was no such transfer experience, but I think if you write a script for PowerShell and specify the server connection string in the YAML file, I think there will be no problems

But this is my opinion

Here is a link to create a PowerShell script [here](https://www.ipswitch.com/blog/building-a-professional-file-transfer-script-in-powershell)